# Display Google Analytics Info on Blog

Tags: google-analytics, jekyll, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to figure out how to display specific parts of Google Analytics on a web page, my Jeykll blog.

I'm using GA to track data, but is there a way to call the API and then be able to display that on a web page? For example, `ga.pageViews`, or something to that extent?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to show the same number across all pages. The easiest thing to do would be to create a Google Data Studio dashboard and then embed that on your blog. The dashboard would be a simple one with a single chart or a single scorecard that displays the total number of pageviews for a given time period.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GA core api to pull the data and use that data anywhere you want. 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

Recommendations:

- This api uses authentication. So use this api to pull data and store it in some database and then pull it from the same to display on the UI.
- You can set it up as a cron job, which runs the api at specific intervals and updates the database that you are using